# Solve general solution of system of first order partial differential equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, partial-derivative

$$u_x + v_y = 0$$
$$v_x - v_y = 0$$
$$v_y - u_x = 0$$

We are instructed to solve the following system of first order equations.  I have no idea where to begin.  I have tried putting this into a matrix with the equations in one multiplied by one with the derivatives to equal a matrix of 0s.  I have tried to find characteristic equations where the solutions will be constant and only have come up with <1,-1> for the gradient of v.  I am not sure if I should simply try to integrate, but I'm almost positive this would not be effective.  Any tips pushing me in the right direction would be welcome.

Partial Differential Equations course

Comment: Add the first and the second and add the second and the third.

Comment: @Urgje So then I obtain $u_x+v_x=0$ and $v_x-u_x=0$, which allows that $v_x=u_x$ or $v+f(y) = u + g(y)$ is this the general solution?

Comment: Actually $u{_x}=0$ and $v{_x}=0$ by subtraction and addition.

Comment: I'm sorry I still don't understand what the general solution would be.  So far the problems have been quite difficult so I'm not sure if that is enough